# How to express requirements between components?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

I have two components, A and B.
Component B requires that A has a certain state.

I can write this as part of B's code,
or I can write this as part of A's code (and maybe add assertions to B)

What should I take into consideration when making such a decision?

#### Edit

In this scenario there might be several B-type components. 
It's also assumed that I can't avoid this situation

#### Edit 2

This often happens when working with frameworks. I usually have a some sort of "global settings", and components that require those settings to be something

Comment: You should probably add more information.  That sounds like a level of coupling that is probably too high.  If B really requires it then perhaps B should manage A's lifecycle and 'hide' B completely.

Comment: I've added more detail. You mean hide A?

Comment: I agree with the comment that this sounds like too high coupling.  That aside, B needs A to have a certain state in order to do what?  Invoke something on A or use it in B for something?

Comment: I've seen this type of thing in composition, which is why i said hide A cuz it sounds like B owns A.  hard to tell without a description of the domain or interactions.

Comment: @KAJ If you want something more specific, this situation arises with global settings used by various frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities:

- Have A implement an interface that will B will check
- Make A create B whenever it has such a state.

Generally, the first solution is used, because ALL Bs refer to A, but A doesn't actually have to know about ALL Bs (you said there were many). In theory, every object should do what it is supposed to do, ignoring anything else exists, unless its a controller object.

With the first solution, B checks what A has.
With the second solution, A becomes the controller of all Bs.

I would say that it's better to have Bs check for A on creation, but in special cases, like when A is your main controller class, it MIGHT be preferable to have A create B.

**Edit as response to Edit 2 by OP**
Yes, in this case it's almost always better to have B check in global settings. Global settings are there so you can check them! The only exception is if A is also the owner of all other components (such as the Game class in XNA)... Even there it would be difficult to choose and just to keep the architecture intact I'd still make B check inside of A, it's just more clean and healthy.

Comment: I agree with psoft here, I lacked the words to say it properly, if you use my second solution, A becomes the "owner" of B.

Comment: I also lean toward this. Maybe I should start seeing global state as a compromise between components.

Comment: It generally is, by encapsulation rules, global "settings" classes should even be solo. That is to say ALL they do is provide the settings for everyone to use. This also generally helps people avoid such problems!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that coupling is too high (at least not from your description of the problem alone).

I think the general answer to your general question comes from the concept of ownership/responsibility that so pervades OO in general. If B needs A to be in some state before doing something, then B must make sure A is in that state before doing it. Responsibility lies with B - put the code in B.

Presumably A has its own life independent of B. Let it be A, man.